# Hive split string to get all the items except first one?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a column data "testdata" like this "**abc,def,ghi,jkl**" and I want to retrieve the output as **"def,ghi,jkl"**

I am able to retrieve the first data like this

```
SELECT split(testdata,'[\,]')[0] FROM tablename;
```

I need a similar single query to get all the items except first one.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this

```
select regexp_extract(testdata,'^(.*?)(?:,)(.*)$', 2) from tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested approach would be:

```
select  substr("abc,def,ghi,jkl",5);

Select substr(testdata,5) FROM tablename;
```

Comment: thanks .But the requirement needed to split based on first occurrence of "," and then take out everything post that.This doesnt split based on "," .Also we shouldn't hardcode the length as the value after the first comma can be dynamic.Means we can have 10 comma delimtted value also.So my solution takes care of these

Answer (score 0):

```
with tablename as (
  select "abc,def,ghi,jkl" as testdata
) -- test data

select regexp_replace(testdata,concat_ws("","^(",split(testdata,"[\,]")[0],",)"),"") as testdata
from tablename; 
+--------------+--+
|   testdata   |
+--------------+--+
| def,ghi,jkl  |
+--------------+--+
```

Note: it won't replace if only one element exist in testdata string.